# C# MySQL as multiline string

Tags: c#, mysql, string

I'm trying to query a multiline mySQL (text) into string[] in c#

```
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT `items` FROM `queue` WHERE `status`='active'", conn); 
object[] que_items = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

items gives (as example):

> item1
>
> item2
>
> item3

didnt't work because it gives an error.
Any help?

Because everyone wants to see error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Also, See https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpidY.png

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace?

Comment: Does not work because it gives error is nice :) Please post the error then!

Comment: ExecuteScalar won't return a collection of result. it will return single result.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'object[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Selman22 What to do about it?

Comment: You need to use `ExecuteReader`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation of `ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) method you can see:

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query

So it returns first result only. If you need all of them you can use `ExecuteReader` method.

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
List<string> results = new List<string>();
while(reader.Read())
{
     results.Add(reader[0].ToString()); // or reader["items"]
}
```

Or you can also use `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(row => row.Field<string>("items"))
                .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** Looks like you want to get first result and split it into an array, so using the `ExecuteScalar` is the right way to do it but you just need to convert the result to `string` and split it:

```
string[] que_items = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                        .ToString()
                        .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I want to get those item1, item2, item3, In a string list.

Comment: so you want to get one record and split it into an array? I'm gonna edit my answer but you should have included that picture in the question beforehand. we don't know how your  data looks like in db